# Partial Index Match One Long Cell Value to Values from 3 Different Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi guys I have no idea how to do it at all since I probably don't get the logic behind building a formula for it so I'm going to ask here instead.

I'm administrating students' photos and have to collect them, and rename them to a consistent format. Basically, I have to do the following:

1. List the photo names by writing a .bat file using a simple command like `dir /b *.jpg *jpeg *png *tiff >ClientList.txt`
2. I create an Excel sheet to look for the students' names and student ID through a main database by performing Index Match
3. I Concatnate the results into a batch of Commands to be placed at Command Prompt to rename every photo at once

As of now, I am stuck at Step 2, doing them manually, because many students did not follow the guidelines and sent in their photos with sometimes only students IDs, sometimes First name, Last Name, sometimes Last Name, First Name; and sometimes a mix of name and student IDs. Also, students use names coming in different languages (Chinese and English)

As such, I want to have a way for Excel to search for the columns that contain English Names, Chinese Names and Student ID and return the closest match so that I don't have to identify them one by one.

I hope my question can be understood as I am not too sure how to explain it thoroughly.

Comment: ... or you could just take the photos of those students that did not follow protocol and throw them in the garbage. If that isn't an option, look into microsoft's fuzzy logic add-in.

Comment: Just manually rename all the files to their students ID.. And your step 2 will be fine. || Index Match is not meant for partial match search. || IMHO, preventing duplicates is more critical here.. If in doubt, just as the respective student to resend/rename their photo with ID. (for those names not found using Index match).